# Regex to replace values that include part of match in replacement in sublime?

Tags: regex, sublimetext, textmate, oniguruma

I've come up with this regex that finds all words that start with `$` and contain `_` underscores:

`\$(\w+)_(\w+)`

I'm basically searching for variables, like `$var_foo` etc.

How do I replace stuff using the regex groups?

For example, how can I remove the underscore and make the next letter uppercase, like `$varFoo` ?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The replacement expression is:

```
\$\1\u\2
```

- `\1`, `\2` are the captures (or `$1`, `$2`)
- `\u` up-cases (see the [Replacement String Syntax section](http://manual.macromates.com/en/regular_expressions#replacement_string_syntax_format_strings)).

See the [Regular Expressions chapter](http://manual.macromates.com/en/regular_expressions#regular_expressions) <sup>(in the  [TextMate docs](http://manual.macromates.com/en/))</sup> for more information.

There's already a package that does this, and more:

- [Brief blog about CaseConversion](http://thecrumb.com/2011/10/27/sublime-text-package-of-the-day-case-conversion/)
- [CaseConversion package](https://bitbucket.org/scottbessler/sublimetextcaseconversion/src)

Comment: Sublime text 3 does not take regex in the "Replace With" field. If I put a regex there, it just dumps that regex as string in the editor. How can I use regex in "Replace" field in sublime?  Basically, I want to search all words (basically hex colour values) beginning with "#" and add some string before and after that word. Using "\#\w+", I can find all such words, but if I do string1\#\w+string2, it outputs it as it is, without replacing regex with actual word.

Comment: @dk49: Use as below:

Find: (#\w+)
Replace: text-before\1text-after