# How can I bulk delete floatval(*)

Tags: sublimetext2, text-editor, sublimetext

I have a heft php file that has a ton of variables like this:

```
floatval($string)
```

`$string` is always a different string but I want to remove all these floats. What is an easy way to remove `floatval($anything)`?

I use Sublime if it matters.

Comment: not sure if we should keep the php tag, it's not really a php problem.

Comment: do you wish to drop the whole expression, or just the `floatval`part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use a regular expression to search for that pattern and do the replacement, as explained in the answer of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10841060/how-to-use-regex-to-replace-stuff-in-sublime). The matching expression would be something like:

```
floatval\(\$([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\)
```

and the replacement one:

```
 \$\1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use search and replace (`ctrl + H`). Also, select the 'Regular Expression' option. Then search for `floatval\(\$[a-zA-Z]*\)` and replace with nothing.

[image: Sublime]